# How do you broadcast a transaction programatically?

Tags: transactions, blockchain.info, bitcoinjs, broadcast

What is the best way to broadcast a transaction to the network programatically? I know that blockchain.info has /pushtx but I'm pretty sure it rejects XHR requests from external sources because of CORS.

Answer (score 4):

You should not use an online service for broadcasting transaction. This online-service would have full control (censor?) over your transaction. The service could analyze your data behavior and/or decide to not broadcast your transaction regarding some rules.

Wladimir van der Laan (current bitcoin-core project maintainer) has written a neat tool: https://github.com/laanwj/bitcoin-submittx

Another option would be to install bitcoin-core, sync (takes serval hours and around 40GB traffic) and use RPC sendrawtransaction.

Comment: If they censor your tx, you'll notice it, so you can use another service to broadcast again. You can also use a new TOR connection for each broadcast, so it's harder to link to a real IP.
Sending a raw transactions from your local node reveals your IP address, so I'd say it's actually worse.

Answer (score 1):

I found what I was looking for. Blockr.io has a good service for publishing transactions to the network. This is the url that you would send a post request to
http://btc.blockr.io/api/v1/tx/push

Make sure to send it the transaction as a post request like this:

{"hex" : your transaction in hex}